# why the jenkins did not checkout the source code in multibranch build

Tags: java, jenkins

when I build a multi pipeline project, I found the dictory only generate one dir:

```
an-superhub-multipipeline_hades
```

and the dir `an-superhub-multipipeline_hades` did not have source code. and other project have 3 dir like this:

```
an-superhub-multipipeline_master
an-superhub-multipipeline_master@libs
an-superhub-multipipeline_master@tmp
```

why would this happen, what should I do to fix it? I want to delete the branch and regerate it, but I did not find any delete option in the UI. Only one option to delete all multibranch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check logs first:

- Job's logs;
- System's logs (go to Manage Jenkins - System logs);
- logs in jenkins home folder.

What are the differences between develop and hades branches?

If you want to recreate job in multibranch pipeline - delete it on gitlab side, then run scan on jenkins multibranch job, and create branch again.

From my point of view it is better to use Gitlab branch source plugin to automate jobs creation in jenkins and create webhooks in auto manner on gitlab side.